# Formula to get date field in Excel sheet SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, excel

I have data in Excel sheet and I need to update SQL Server DB table by using Excel sheet data, I am able to write SQL Server Query and get the data. However I am not getting date field in date format, it's rendered as a normal number.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cell B2 try this -

```
="Select " & TEXT(A2,"DD/MM/YYYY")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
="select '" & TEXT(A2, "dd/mm/yy") & "' from Table "
```